# What other word could I use?

Tags: phrase-usage, synonyms

What other word (easier one) can I use rather than "appreciate" in the phrase "I appreciate your help." ?

By easier I mean for someone who doesn't speak well english.

Comment: *Appreciate* is probably one of the most common words in English. What's wrong with the normal *Thank you for your help*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generally use the word **[value](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/value)** in the same way as **[appreciate](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/appreciate)**. For example,

> I **value** your help
>   I **value** your advice
>   I **value** your contribution

The main difference is that **value** is more objective, whereas **appreciate** is more personal. According to [this NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20value%2CI%20appreciate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20value%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20appreciate%3B%2Cc0), up until 1900, **value** was more widely used than **appreciate**.